# Hibernate: How to set a field of foreign key to null if it has too be defined in its table?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I know the title might be unclear a bit so let me explain better:

I have 2 Tables with corresponding Hibernate entities. 
 The first entity, InventoryRegionEntity, contains 2 members of the type InventoryDataCenterEntity.

The first member is mandatory, but the second one is optional and can be null in DB.

My problem is that when I wan to save an InventoryRegionEntity object to db, I get :

```
{
  "severity": "HIGH",
  "message": "ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.gms.model.inventory.InventoryDataCenterEntity; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.gms.model.inventory.InventoryDataCenterEntity",
  "requestURI": "/global-management-system/v1/region-inventory",
  "type": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException",
  "stackTrace": null
}
```

The code is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory_region")
public class InventoryRegionEntity{

    @Id
    @Column(name="region", unique = true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private Region region;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="primarydc_name")
    private InventoryDataCenterEntity primaryDC;

    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="secondarydc_name")
    private InventoryDataCenterEntity secondaryDC;

    private boolean anycast;

    public boolean isAnycast () {
        return anycast;
    }

    public void setAnycast ( boolean anycast ) {
        this.anycast = anycast;
    }

    public Region getRegion () {
        return this.region;
    }

    public void setRegion ( Region region ) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public InventoryDataCenterEntity getPrimaryDC () {
        return primaryDC;
    }

    public void setPrimaryDC ( InventoryDataCenterEntity primaryDC ) {
        this.primaryDC = primaryDC;
    }

    public InventoryDataCenterEntity getSecondaryDC () {
        return secondaryDC;
    }

    public void setSecondaryDC ( InventoryDataCenterEntity secondaryDC ) {
        this.secondaryDC = secondaryDC;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory_data_center")
public class InventoryDataCenterEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "azure_config", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    @Convert(converter = AzureConfigurationToStringConverter.class)
     private List<PodCollection> azureDataCenters;

    @JoinColumn(name = "monitoringprefix")
    private String monitoringPrefix;

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName ( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<PodCollection> getAzureDataCenters () {
        return azureDataCenters;
    }

    public void setAzureDataCenters ( List<PodCollection> azureDataCenters ) {
        this.azureDataCenters = azureDataCenters;
    }

    public String getMonitoringPrefix() {
        return monitoringPrefix;
    }

    public void setMonitoringPrefix(String monitoringPrefix) {
        this.monitoringPrefix = monitoringPrefix;
    }
}
```

and the Region table is:

[image]

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like it complains that you didn't add `@GeneratedValue` annotation to the ID field.

Comment: It says clearly `ids must be assign manually`. Since you are not using `@GeneratedValue` you need to set value `region` manually. Can u set a value for `region` and check?

Comment: Guys, Region has two fields: primaryDc (Mandatory) and secondaryDc (should be optional: a dc value or null). The values for these dc fields must be declared in the DataCenter table. Hope the case is clearer now :)

Comment: Can you please add your code where you are persisting your entity? Although, it does look like problem caused by the ID.